# Getting an error message from a sql server driver in my symfony project

Tags: sql-server, symfony

I have tried to install the ODBC driver 18 for SQL Server in my symfony project. I am getting the following error messages. I wanted to ask if anyone could knows the solution for these.

> An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:16000069:STORE
> routines::unregistered scheme:scheme=file][error:80000002:system
> library::No such file or direc     tory:calling
> stat(/usr/local/etc/openssl@3/certs)][error:16000069:STORE
> routines::unregistered scheme:scheme=file]

Environment details:
symfony version: 5.4.16
php8.1
Homebrew 3.6.16
apache 2.4.54

Comment: Have you tried searching? `"No such file or directory" "/usr/local/etc/openssl@3/certs"` seems quite relevant, ["unregistered scheme": openssl@3 doesn't create its own certs directory? #4030](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4030)

Answer (score 2):

@AlwaysLearning's answer did help me.From the article linked, I checked the openssl@3 folder and I did see there was a cert.pem file. I then created a certs directory and copied the cert.pem file into that directory. That got of rid of my error message.
[image]

I did encounter an additional issue where I needed to add TrustServerCertificate parameter to the end of my connection string that is used to connect to the SQL server.

```
;TrustServerCertificate=1
```